# Oneliner which prints groups and their numbers which start with a '1'?

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have to write an oneliner which print system groups and their identifiers, for all groups whose identifiers start with '1'. 
For example, the result of `cat` command on `/etc/group` is this:

I must print:

```
users 100 
libuuid 101 
netdev 102 
crontab 103
........
penny 1002 
leonard 1003 
sheldon 1004
```

Comment: OK, and what is your question?

Comment: Is this an assignment? What have you tried so far? What is giving your trouble?

Comment: Please don't **[cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079942/oneliner-which-print-system-groups-and-their-identifiers-for-all-groups-whose-i)**

Comment: I don't know how to realize this oneliner. Could you give me an idea, please?

Comment: BTW, you can upvote answers that were helpful to you. Not sure if you realized this or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AWK` to do this more effectively.

```
$ awk -F: '$3 ~ /^1/ {print $1, $3}' /etc/group
daemon 1
uucp 10
man 12
proxy 13
kmem 15
users 100
libuuid 101
crontab 102
fuse 103
avahi-autoipd 104
scanner 105
messagebus 106
colord 107
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice any consistent pattern with groups and their corresponding group numbers that start with a 1?

```
$ head -20 /etc/group
root:x:0:
bin:x:1:
daemon:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:logcheck
tty:x:5:
disk:x:6:
lp:x:7:
mem:x:8:
kmem:x:9:
wheel:x:10:saml
cdrom:x:11:
mail:x:12:
man:x:15:
dialout:x:18:
floppy:x:19:
games:x:20:
tape:x:30:
video:x:39:
ftp:x:50:
```

One pattern that immediately jumps out at me is that all the group numbers are prefixed by a colon, `:`. So you could look for lines that contain `:1`, for example.

And since we're talking about looking for patterns in a file, you should immediately think of the tool, `grep`. This tool can look for patterns, and then print out the corresponding lines that contain the pattern.

So if we do a little assembly of the bits that we know:

```
$ grep ":1" /etc/group
bin:x:1:
wheel:x:10:saml
cdrom:x:11:
mail:x:12:
man:x:15:
dialout:x:18:
floppy:x:19:
users:x:100:
systemd-journal:x:190:
systemd-journal-gateway:x:191:
usbmuxd:x:113:
qemu:x:107:
rtkit:x:172:
abrt:x:173:
avahi-autoipd:x:170:
oprofile:x:16:
mock:x:135:
stapusr:x:156:
stapsys:x:157:
stapdev:x:158:
```

#### Formatting the output

If you must format the above output so that it conforms to this:

```
user 123
```

Then you could use `sed` to clean it up:

```
$ grep ":1" /etc/group | sed 's/:\(x:\)*/ /g' | head -5
bin 1 
wheel 10 saml
cdrom 11 
mail 12 
man 15
```

The `head` command is just to limit the output here to 5 lines.

Comment: all-in-one: `sed 's/:[x:]*/ /g;/ 1/H;g;/\(\n.*\)\{5\}/q;d'`

Comment: @mikeserv - show off 

Comment: it took me a minute to figure out how you kept the `s///g` from doing spaces everywhere - then I realized you tacked on the optional `\(x:\)*` but the first `:` was not optional. That was clever - and I remembered some stuff I did with counting patterns the other day. What's kinda neat is `s/\(pattern\)*/\1/` always gets the *last* one in a pattern series. So you can count occurrences just by telling whether it is successful. New knowledge - yeah I showed off a little. Sorry.